# How to use Local docker image in kubernetes via kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I created customize Docker Image and stored in my local system Now I want use that Docker Image via kubectl .

Docker image:-
1:- docker build -t backend:v1 .

Then Kubernetes file:-

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  namespace: web-console
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: mail_auth_pass
        - name: mail_auth_user
        - name: mail_from
        - name: mail_greeting
        - name: mail_service
        - name: mail_sign
        - name: mongodb_url
          value: mongodb://mongodb.mongodb.svc.cluster.local/console
        - name: server_host
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: server_port
          value: "3000"
        - name: server_sessionSecret
          value: "1234"
          image: backend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: backend
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Command to run kubectl:

```bash
kubectl create -f  backend-deployment.yaml
```

Getting the error:

```
error: error validating "backend-deployment.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[9]): unknown field "image" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[9]): unknown field "imagePullPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: `image:` is indented one step too many.  If you’re not using a purely-local Kubernetes, there also might be a step of “push the image to a registry” involved.

Answer (score 31):

### Local Registry

Set the local registry first using this command

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

### Image Tag

Given a `Dockerfile`, the image could be built and tagged this easy way:

`docker build . -t localhost:5000/my-image`

Push the image on the local repo:

`docker push localhost:5000/my-image`

### Using the image

The pushed image can now be used:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: localhost:5000/my-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

### Deploy Pod

The pod can be deployed using:

`kubectl create -f pod.yml`

Hope this comes in handy :)

Comment: After the `docker build`, we need to push it to the local registry: `docker push localhost:5000/my-image`. After that, it works fine as you described :)

Comment: On Katacoda, when I tested this, it allows me to get the image even without pushing the image to the local repo, but it may work only with `imagePullPolicy: Never`

Comment: Interesting, I was testing this locally using Docker for Desktop and it only worked when I did the `docker push ...` :)

Comment: there might be some differences between both docker for Desktop and the one on Ubuntu :)

Comment: After you perform the above you will inevitably want to change your image. but you will have "Never" in your .yaml file, change it to "Always" and build, push. This will keep pulling after each build. This worked for me. I know it sounds basic but I was stuck until I tried this.

Comment: None of this works for me ‍♂️ - though I'm trying with kubectl run instead of yaml deploy. --image=localhost:5000/my-image --image-pull-policy='Never' and it fails with ErrImageNeverPull

Comment: Error response from daemon: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused :(

Answer (score 3):

As the error specifies `unknown field "image" and unknown field "imagePullPolicy"`

There is syntax error in your kubernetes deployment file.

Make these changes in your yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  namespace: web-console
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: backend
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: mail_auth_pass
        - name: mail_auth_user
        - name: mail_from
        - name: mail_greeting
        - name: mail_service
        - name: mail_sign
        - name: mongodb_url
          value: mongodb://mongodb.mongodb.svc.cluster.local/console
        - name: server_host
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: server_port
          value: "3000"
        - name: server_sessionSecret
          value: "1234"
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Validate your kubernetes yaml file online using https://kubeyaml.com/

Or with `kubectl apply --validate=true --dry-run=true -f deployment.yaml`

Hope this helps.