# Use custom broker for Akri with local docker image

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use a custom broker for Akri but do not know how to specify which docker image to launch if I don't use a container registry. I have a docker container build on the fedora core os machine that I am deploying akri to. But in the example there is only a path used to a container registry.
Just using the name of the docker image on the machine didn't work. Also I am not completely sure where the image is stored even after searching for it with other explanation on that subject.
Here is the example from Akri: https://docs.akri.sh/development/broker-development
They use this line:
 `--set udev.configuration.brokerPod.image.repository="ghcr.io/brokers/camera-broker"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local registry like in this answer works for this case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64500000/10784870

I didn't know enough on the topic of kubernetes and helm to connect my question of akri broker to this answer.